# Mi programa no compila porque el struct no está creado, cuando en realidad sí lo está

Tags: c++

Me encuentro resolviendo exámenes viejos de ejemplo, y este es el problema que encontré:

> Escriba una función genérica (template) llamada ampliar() que reciba como
> argumentos un objeto llamado archname de tipo string y un arreglo de la clase vector (STL) llamado x
> que contiene structs de 2 miembros: valor (genérico) y pos (char). El string archname corresponde al
> nombre de un archivo binario. La función debe agregar al archivo el dato (valor) de cada elemento del
> arreglo x. Los agregados se hacen al principio del archivo si pos contiene ‘f’ y al final del archivo si
> pos contiene ‘b’.

Adjunto lo que tengo planteado.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

struct Tipo {
    T valor;
    char pos;
};

template<typename T>
void ampliar(string archname, vector<Tipo>x) {
    fstream arch(archname, ios::binary);
    for(int i = 0; i<x.size(); i++) {
        if(x[i].pos == 'f') {
            arch.seekp(0);
            arch.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&x[i].valor), sizeof(x[i].valor));
        } else if(x[i].pos == 'b') {
            arch.seekg(0, arch.end);
            arch.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&x[i].valor), sizeof(x[i].valor));
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    
    return 0;
}
```

Como dije en el título, el error que devuelve al ejecutar se refiere a que no encuentra el tipo de dato 'T', entonces, dónde debería inicializar el struct?

Comment: En el título no aclaras nada de lo que te falla.

Comment: Bueno. OK. Ya lo arreglé.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El enunciado dice:

> ...que contiene structs de 2 miembros: valor (genérico) y pos (char)...

Entonces, tu `struct` debería ser una `template`:

```
template< typename T > struct Tipo {
    T valor;
    char pos;
};
```

Con lo que tu función quedaría:

```
template< typename T >
void ampliar( const string &archname, const vector< Tipo< T > > &x ) {
    ...
}
```

<sub>Nota: tu código para **añadir al principio** no va a funcionar. No estás añadiendo, estás **sobreescribiendo**.</sub>